# How do you create a hyperlink in AX?

Tags: gridview, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've been working on an AX project that takes text files from an outside vendor, transforms the files into XML data and saves the data in AX tables for the user to review using AX cues.

I need to link to the original source text file from the AX cue's gridview. But I can't construct a hyperlink in AX to the original text file stored on a network drive.

Has anyone figured out how to do this in AX 2012 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it on the grid, I don't believe there is a native way to do this, but it's easy enough.

Just override the `mouseDown()` method on the grid and put:

`infolog.urlLookup(@'//127.0.0.1/');`

Where you replace the part with the network share of your record value. You can play around with the grid field font to make it look like a link if you want.

If you wanted a URL on a form, you use a regular `MenuItemButton` but set the property `Style = Link`. This would make the menu button "look" like a link, then you'd use the same code above to launch it.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You may use WebSiteURL EDT as done in standard on EPWebSiteParameters table for internal and external URL for EP.